# StanfordNLP: models from kbp not found (Eclipse)

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am a bit new to Java and Eclipse. I usually use python and Nltk for NLP task..
I am trying to follow the tutorial provided [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html)

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BasicPipelineExample {

public static String text = "Joe Smith was born in California. " +
      "In 2017, he went to Paris, France in the summer. " +
      "His flight left at 3:00pm on July 10th, 2017. " +
      "After eating some escargot for the first time, Joe said, \"That was delicious!\" " +
      "He sent a postcard to his sister Jane Smith. " +
      "After hearing about Joe's trip, Jane decided she might go to France one day.";



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    // set the list of annotators to run
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,depparse,coref,kbp,quote");
    // set a property for an annotator, in this case the coref annotator is being set to use the neural algorithm
    props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural");
    // build pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // create a document object
    CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument(text);
    // annnotate the document
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    // examples

    // 10th token of the document
    CoreLabel token = document.tokens().get(10);
    System.out.println("Example: token");
    System.out.println(token);
    System.out.println();

    // text of the first sentence
    String sentenceText = document.sentences().get(0).text();
    System.out.println("Example: sentence");
    System.out.println(sentenceText);
    System.out.println();

    // second sentence
    CoreSentence sentence = document.sentences().get(1);

    // list of the part-of-speech tags for the second sentence
    List<String> posTags = sentence.posTags();
    System.out.println("Example: pos tags");
    System.out.println(posTags);
    System.out.println();

    // list of the ner tags for the second sentence
    List<String> nerTags = sentence.nerTags();
    System.out.println("Example: ner tags");
    System.out.println(nerTags);
    System.out.println();

    // constituency parse for the second sentence
    Tree constituencyParse = sentence.constituencyParse();
    System.out.println("Example: constituency parse");
    System.out.println(constituencyParse);
    System.out.println();

    // dependency parse for the second sentence
    SemanticGraph dependencyParse = sentence.dependencyParse();
    System.out.println("Example: dependency parse");
    System.out.println(dependencyParse);
    System.out.println();

    // kbp relations found in fifth sentence
    List<RelationTriple> relations =
        document.sentences().get(4).relations();
    System.out.println("Example: relation");
    System.out.println(relations.get(0));
    System.out.println();

    // entity mentions in the second sentence
    List<CoreEntityMention> entityMentions = sentence.entityMentions();
    System.out.println("Example: entity mentions");
    System.out.println(entityMentions);
    System.out.println();

    // coreference between entity mentions
    CoreEntityMention originalEntityMention = document.sentences().get(3).entityMentions().get(1);
    System.out.println("Example: original entity mention");
    System.out.println(originalEntityMention);
    System.out.println("Example: canonical entity mention");
    System.out.println(originalEntityMention.canonicalEntityMention().get());
    System.out.println();

    // get document wide coref info
    Map<Integer, CorefChain> corefChains = document.corefChains();
    System.out.println("Example: coref chains for document");
    System.out.println(corefChains);
    System.out.println();

    // get quotes in document
    List<CoreQuote> quotes = document.quotes();
    CoreQuote quote = quotes.get(0);
    System.out.println("Example: quote");
    System.out.println(quote);
    System.out.println();

    // original speaker of quote
    // note that quote.speaker() returns an Optional
    System.out.println("Example: original speaker of quote");
    System.out.println(quote.speaker().get());
    System.out.println();

    // canonical speaker of quote
    System.out.println("Example: canonical speaker of quote");
    System.out.println(quote.canonicalSpeaker().get());
    System.out.println();

  }

}
```

but I always get the following output containing an error, and this happen for all modules relating to kbp, and I did add the jar files as requested by the tutorial:

> Adding annotator tokenize No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to
>   PTBTokenizer. Adding annotator ssplit Adding annotator pos Loading POS
>   tagger from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger
>   ... done [0.9 sec]. Adding annotator lemma Adding annotator ner
>   Loading classifier from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ...
>   done [1.4 sec]. Loading classifier from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ...
>   done [1.8 sec]. Loading classifier from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
>   ... done [0.6 sec]. **Exception in thread "main"
>   edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Couldn't read TokensRegexNER
>   from edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/regexner_caseless.tab**  at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator.readEntries(TokensRegexNERAnnotator.java:593)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator.(TokensRegexNERAnnotator.java:293)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.NERCombinerAnnotator.setUpFineGrainedNER(NERCombinerAnnotator.java:209)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.NERCombinerAnnotator.(NERCombinerAnnotator.java:152)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.ner(AnnotatorImplementations.java:68)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$45(StanfordCoreNLP.java:546)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$70(StanfordCoreNLP.java:625)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:126)  at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)  at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:149)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:495)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:201)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:194)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:181)
>     at NLP.Start.main(Start.java:13) Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/regexner_caseless.tab" as
>   class path, filename or URL   at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:481)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readerFromString(IOUtils.java:618)   at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator.readEntries(TokensRegexNERAnnotator.java:590)
>     ... 14 more

Do you have any idea to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add `stanford-corenlp-3.9.1-models.jar` to your class path.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the [models page](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html), there are is a separate model download for the kbp material.  Perhaps you have access to stanford-english-corenlp-2018-02-27-models, but not access to stanford-english-kbp-corenlp-2018-02-27-models?  I would guess this because it appears that other models were found from what you provided us in the question.